# Text length filter Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications

I create a telegram bot, which collects user info into gSheets. I want to create a filter. If the user wrote less than 10 symbols, bot says that this is not enough. When I tested it, bot just stopped, but JSON was still coming and being processed.

```
  function doPost(e) {
    let contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents); 
    let chat_id = contents.message.chat.id; 
    let text = contents.message.text; 
  
    if (text.length > 10) {
      sendText(chat_id,"✅ Great!");
    }
    else (text.length < 10) {
      sendText(chat_id," Its not enough.");
    }
  }
```

Comment: I removed (text.length <10) but its still not working

Comment: Did you checked Log, what response you're getting , can we  see the screenshot of returned text  message

Comment: @vector https://imgur.com/a/3HE1kOS

Comment: I still don't understand this `If user wrote less 10 symbols, bot says that this is not enough. ` and what log you're getting when you're trying to check what `.length` is returning

Comment: If text.length > 10 = good;
else = bad;

idk why you don't understand this elementary thing. If user wrote text less that 10 symbols, bot says that information isn't enough. If user wrote MORE 10 symbols, bot accepts this text.

i dont have log system for this easy bot. I send screen that json send me if i write text

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add all the relevant details directly into the question. Please bear in mind that logs and error messages should be added as text, not as image.

Comment: if (text.length >= 10) {
      sendText(chat_id,"✅ Great!");
    }
    else if(text.length < 10) {
      sendText(chat_id," Its not enough.");
    }`  What's sendText()?

Comment: sendText() is message sender function https://imgur.com/a/5POtMF0

Comment: @evolji `why you don't understand this elementary thing.`  You need to understand the difference between `symbols` and `characters`, that even person who don't know elementary can tell you!

Comment: @vector i know about symbols and characters, but there no matter, because I checked a text length from . length JS function.